# How to run just one ASP.NET Development Server in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have several web application projects in one solution.
When I start debugging one of those web applications I noticed that the ASP.NET Development Server starts for all web applications in my solution.
How can I determine to just one ASP.NET Development Server to be started?
Is this even possible?

I don't want to have my system tray filled with icons of all my web applications.

Thanks!

---

**Duplicate**: [Why do VS2008 spawn one Cassini for each web-site/application when going into debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127093/why-do-vs2008-spawn-one-cassini-for-each-web-site-application-when-going-into-deb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you, I have a similar issue since there are several web remoting projects in my solution. What I did was set up virtual directories for each in IIS then just right-click the each project and select properties. On the Web tab I then set the server to use when debugging to IIS. This causes Visual Studio to use the single instance of IIS instead of opening a dozen separate web development servers for each project. When you debug, attach to w3wp.exe processes.

Comment: I was asked a question about this at work today too.  Just to be clear, if you attach to the wswp.exe process, will break points in any and all websites get hit when the websites are used?

Comment: In my experience, yes. When you attach you are attaching to all the DLLs loaded into the worker process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can't stop this behaviour and is by design.

This because of the way that VS attaches its debugger to target processes. i.e. you couldn't have two instances of VS attaching to the same process. Hence multiple instances of the cassini web server, one for each VS session.